# why TI starterware examples do not clear correctly BSS segment when compiled using CodeSourcery gcc

Tags: gcc, arm, codesourcery

I ran into severe troubles with beaglebone running TI AM3359arm. I'm using code sourcery to compile code. I tried to compile one of the examples, called enet_lwip, which uses lightweight IP (lwip) to provide http server.

The application crashes at certain point. By debugging I have found, that it is this piece of code, which is responsible for it:

```
unsigned int lwIPInit(LWIP_IF *lwipIf)
{

    struct ip_addr ip_addr;

    struct ip_addr net_mask;

    struct ip_addr gw_addr;

    unsigned int *ipAddrPtr;

    static unsigned int lwipInitFlag = 0;

    unsigned int ifNum;

    unsigned int temp;

    /* do lwip library init only once */
    if(0 == lwipInitFlag)
    {
        lwip_init();
    }
```

A *very funny thing* happens to this: one would expect, that *lwipInitFlag* gets initialized to *0* and hence the function calls lwip_init();

Well, this does not happen even the very first time the lwIPInit function gets called. The reason for this is, that the variable *lwipInitFlag is not set to 0*.

I would like to know why this is. If such initialization appears in the code, compiler should generate sequence to null it. But probably because it is preceded by *static* modifier, it leaves it 'as is'. Why?

The lwipInitFlag is in .bss linker section, which points to DDR memory. How can I assure, that such static assignments get initialized?

For the moment I'll hack the code for lwIP to see if this works, but it is just a warning for me, that there might be another statically declared variables somewhere in the libraries, which do not get initialized.

Any hint how to resolve this?

---

Adding more information to this: after your fruitful hints I think I have even more mess in how it should work. So: It is true, that I do not call/link crt*.o. On the other hand the TI starterware platform contains initialization asm source, which DOES BSS cleanup. It does it between addresses _bss_start and _bss_end.

When looking into linker script, everything looks pretty ordinary:

```
SECTIONS
{

        . = 0x80000000;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        .startcode     :
        {
               *init.o      (.text)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);
        .text      :
        {
                *(.text)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);

        .data :
        {
                *(.data)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);

        _bss_start = .;
        .bss :
        {
                *(.bss)
        }
        . = ALIGN(4);

        _bss_end = .;

        _stack = 0x87FFFFF8;
}
```

So _bss_start is address *before* BSS block and _bss_end is *at the end* of the block. **The trouble is what map the Codesourcery generates**.

When looking at the end of BSS in generated map file, I can see this:

```
 COMMON         0x80088f0c      0x200 ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/system_config/Debug/libsystem_config.a(interrupt.o)
                0x80088f0c                fnRAMVectors
                0x8008910c                . = ALIGN (0x4)
                0x8008910c                _bss_end = .
                0x87fffff8                _stack = 0x87fffff8
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/drivers/Debug/libdrivers.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/utils/Debug/libutils.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/beaglebone/platform/Debug/libplatform.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/system_config/Debug/libsystem_config.a
LOAD /opt/CodeSourcery/arm-none-eabi/lib//libc.a
LOAD /opt/CodeSourcery/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.2//libgcc.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/drivers/Debug/libdrivers.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/utils/Debug/libutils.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/beaglebone/platform/Debug/libplatform.a
LOAD ../binary/armv7a/gcc/am335x/system_config/Debug/libsystem_config.a
LOAD /opt/CodeSourcery/arm-none-eabi/lib//libc.a
LOAD /opt/CodeSourcery/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.5.2//libgcc.a
OUTPUT(Debug/bbdidt.out elf32-littlearm)

.bss.pageTable  0x8008c000     0x4000
 .bss.pageTable
                0x8008c000     0x4000 Debug/enetLwip.o

.bss.ram        0x80090000        0x4
 .bss.ram       0x80090000        0x4 Debug/lwiplib.o
```

There is clearly 'something'. **There is another BSS section after the _bss_end**, which contains a lot of stuff which is expected to be zeroed, but it is not zeroed, because zeroing finishes at address given by _bss_end.

The probable reason why this is done like this is, that the **pageTable** is statically declared and required to have 16kiB boundary address:

```
static volatile unsigned int pageTable[4*1024] __attribute__((aligned(16*1024)));
```

So as there is a gap between last linker declared BSS segment and pageTable, it places the _bss_end in the middle of the bss segment.

Now the question is, how to tell to linker (I'm using for this arm-none-eabi-ld) that _bss_end should be really at the end of BSS and not somewhere in the middle?

Many thanks

Comment: It seems that *ALL* static variables are not initialised. The *netif_add* contains similar static variable declaration and the code is not performed either. So this reduces to general problem: why CodeSourcery v.4.5.2 does not initialize static variables.

Comment: What is `init.o`?  Do you have the source? `init.o` is traditionally responsible for clearing `BSS` and setting up the stack.  The fact you can debug anything indicates that you have some startup code. Also, how is it started?  Does this get burned to flash so a reset vector jumps to the first part of the binary or are you loading via a boot loader?  The boot loader could be setting up stack, etc.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Init.o (hence init.S source) contains initialization of stack and clears BSS as well. It clears however BSS only between addresses _bss_start and _bss_end. My linked code however points _bss_end not at the very end of the BSS section, but somewhere in the middle. Hence the init.S code initializes only fraction of BSS section. It does not initialise either the .data segment. And I've noticed, that there are some variables as well. As for data, this is clear. Because it is (somewhere) clearly stated, that this section is not setup, but the BSS should be setup correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for all these comments. It was for me almost a detective work. At the end I have changed the linker script to get something like this:

```
SECTIONS
{

        . = 0x80000000;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        .startcode     :
        {
               *init.o      (.text)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);
        .text      :
        {
                *(.text)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);

        .data :
        {
                *(.data)
        }

        . = ALIGN(4);

        _bss_start = .;
        .bss :
        {
                *(.bss)
                *(COMMON)
                *(.bss.*)
        }
        . = ALIGN(4);

        _bss_end = .;

        _stack = 0x87FFFFF8;
}
```

So I basically forced linker to include into BSS segment all the sub-segments which start with **COMMON** and **.bss.**.

This apparently resolves the issue as the linker now generates correct map such, that it places _bss_end pointer really to the last address of BSS section.

So my soft now runs correctly, gets PHY running. I still cannot acquire the DHCP, but I guess this is a problem of uninitialised .data segment. LwIP uses at some places static assignments as

```
static u32_t xid = 0xABCD0000;
```

which is going into .data segment, but apparently it does not get initialised and hence I cannot get any DHCP anwer... but this is another story

thanks to all

Comment: +1 Now that you have explained things in a comment in the question, it is clear that `*(.bss.*)` in the `.bss` section is what fixes this.  Can you edit your question to make it more concise.  You have other issues with the linker file like `.rodata` which you may eventually hit.  Also, you can probably save space by aliasing the `pageTable` with the `init.o` code.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that **no** statics are initialised makes me wonder: how have you come by your startup code?  This code is required to perform the initialisations.

See http://doc.ironwoodlabs.com/arm-arm-none-eabi/html/getting-started/sec-cs3-startup.html - section 5.2.3 which says:

---

The C startup function is declared as follows:

```
void __cs3_start_c (void) __attribute__ ((noreturn));
```

This function performs the following steps:

- Initialize all .data-like sections by copying their contents. For example, ROM-profile linker scripts use this mechanism to initialize writable data in RAM from the read-only data program image.
- ... etc

---

It sounds like you might be lacking that code.

Comment: Yes, it is not the compiler's job to initialize static data. The crt*.o files normally take care of this. If you use `-nostdlib` then you have to provide your own. The `.bss` section need only be initialized with zeros.